# [Swift4]UIRefreshControl Indicator appear at different position

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make an iOS app, using Xcode 10.1 (10B61) and Swift4.

I have an issue about UIRefreshControl Indicator appearance, like the image below.

[image: IssueImage]
UIRefreshControl script is written in each TableViewController class (same code about refresh func).

```
class TableViewController1: UITableViewController  {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

---

```
class TableViewController2: UITableViewController  {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

Anybody please give me some advise.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you are missing to set the frame or offset for `UIRefreshControl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of combination of things.

1. You're using large headers for navigation controller. That makes `TableViewController` (actually any scrollable view) to put its `refreshControl` on navigation bar . This behaviour was introduced in iOS 11 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/2908999-preferslargetitles
2. You're using two scrollable views and one of them binds to navigation bar and another is not. During debug I've found out that the first scrollable view in hierarchy attached its `refreshControl` to navigation bar.

So, that's means we can fix it by putting some fake or dummy scrollable view somewhere on the bottom of hierarchy in order to it binds its `refreshControl` to navigation bar first. Starting from iOS 11 any scrollable view may have `refreshControl` and its "binded" even if you don't declare it explicitly.

In your case you might just add `UIScrollView` before container in this way:

`- View
-- Safe Area
-- UIScrollView (dummy)
-- ContainerView
---- TableView 1
---- TableView 2
...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this--

```
class TableViewController2: UITableViewController  {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
  //Updated code.. this will fix it
  self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)

}
```

Let us know .. is working ?

Comment: but this time new allocations has happened.. so there I have doubt over to added view in tableView..

Answer (score 0):

TableviewController 1

```
class TableViewController1: UITableViewController  {

    var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
    tableView1.addSubview(refreshControl)    // Added Line

}
```

TableviewController 2

```
class TableViewController2: UITableViewController  {

    var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onRefresh), for: .valueChanged)

    tableView2.addSubview(refreshControl)    // Added Line

}
```